# Resolving promise with ionic/ui-routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm having some problems figuring out why my promise isn't resolving the way I would expect it to. I'm using Ionic/ui-routing.

my service:

```
return {
    all: function () {
        $localForage.getItem('foo').then(function (bar) {
            return bar;
        });
    }
};
```

When I log data to console, I see the objects that localForage returns from indexeddb.

my apps.js:

```
.state('tab.foo', {
    url: '/foo',
    views: {
        'tab-foo': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-foo.html',
            controller: 'fooCtrl as foo'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        getData: function (Service) {
            return Service.all();
        }
    }
})
```

In my foo controller:

```
this.foo = getData;
```

When I do this, foo in the controller is undefined, any ideas why? When loggig to console I can see that the service is called by apps.js, I can see that it is resolved because I see the data in the console. Using ui-router I would expect it wouldn't load the view/controller until everything is resolved.

I used the following as inspiration, only without the $q service.
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/e1isWkxNl1FWgzFilUyT?p=preview). Because controller will be available as foo, we should do it like this:

The controller assignement into some property `myData`

```
.controller('fooCtrl', function($scope, getData) {
  this.myData = getData;
})
```

The template call would contain both, controller (foo) and its property myData

```
resolved stuff:
<pre>{{foo.myData | json}}</pre>
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/e1isWkxNl1FWgzFilUyT?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your reponse! However it still doesn't seem to work. When I substitute the promise in the service with a regular service it does seem to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/gpVwLuLshfZ8qvj8PIfd?p=preview. When I log to the console in the apps.js the value of Service.all() is also undefined.

Comment: Not sure what is the issue ;( because your plunker seems to work and may as well. so what is wrong? I am ready to help, but now really really not sure, what is wrong ;(

Comment: To me it seems like a problem with the promise in the service. When I log bar in the service, I do get data. When I log Service.all() in apps.js it is undefined.

Comment: Just a second. What are you talking about: Plunker? or your real app? because, I would say, that my plunker, and even yours - with the extension of a service is working. Correct?

Comment: I created more "real like" example, with a real JSON and $http. Again it is wokring: http://plnkr.co/edit/1q8V3BWyzMaMYx0PU6yS?p=preview

Comment: Correct, I was talking about my real app. Looking at your last plunker I found the problem. The solution was that changing     resolve: {
        getData: function (Service) {
            return Service.all();
        } to     resolve: {
        return getData: function (Service) {
            return Service.all();
        }. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad that it helped, enjoy angular/ionic world ;)